# Send a GET request to an API from a different origin

Tags: excel, xml, vba, api, rest

I've been trying to get a json file from an API using an Excel VBA Macro, but apparently the API blocks external access and can only be accessed from the provider website, through a JavaScript form. Is there a workaround for this? Is using a proxy enough to change the 'origin' setting at the header? If so, which changes should be applied to my code block below?

```
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP.6.0")
xmlhttp.Open "GET", sUrl, False
xmlhttp.setProxy 2, "https://www.allowedoriginurl.com.br"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
xmlhttp.send
```

The above code returns a response with a script called "BlockExternalAccess" and a list of allowed origins.

I'm a self-taught amateur programmer, so I apologize in advance if this question is too basic, but I couldn't find anything similar on this forum.

Comment: So you'd like us to help you circumvent their security?

Comment: Not really; If it's illegal I won't go any further. I'm trying to scrap some data from their website. I can just make a macro that would click buttons, fill forms and retrieve what I need, but the API method could make things a lot faster. The way I see It, I'm just skipping unecessary steps, since there is no need to have a registered account on their website for this data.

Comment: If it's restricted to certain origins then it's not an "external" API, and they mean for you not to use it like one.